# How can I add a border that sits behind a grid stack with HTML & CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to figure out how to accomplish this design. The image had a grid stack with a border that allow the grid to sort of pop off the page.

[image: Grid items with a red border behind them]

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.contact-form-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}

.contact-form {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.contact-form:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: -10px;
  right: -10px;
  bottom: -10px;
  border: 3px solid red;
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="contact-form-container">
  <form class="contact-form">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name">
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
    <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not clear from your HTML what outcome you're after. You don't have the sort of two-column layout shown in your graphic (or _any_ layout, really). How does the drop shadow relate? Please revise your post to be more specific.

Comment: My apologies for not specifying in the post that my code wasn't matching the image. I need to accomplish what the image has - the code is just placeholder.

Comment: Please **revise your post** to be more specific. See [ask] and take the [tour] for more tips.

Answer (score 2):

Your code sample seems to do this just fine already.  The only changes I made was to center the `.contact-form-container` and the adjust the specific positions on the `::before` selector

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.contact-form-container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
}

.contact-form {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.contact-form:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: -20px;
  right: -20px;
  bottom: 5px;
  border: 3px solid red;
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="contact-form-container">
  <form class="contact-form">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name">
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
    <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're already pretty close to the answer.

The issue is that you're using `-10px` for the top and the bottom values. That means it's going out (away) from the element that it's supposed to go behind. That is why this works for the left and right. If you set the top and bottom be `10px` it will go in and be behind the item.

```css
body {
    display: grid;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    place-items: center;
}

.contact-form-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}

.contact-form {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.contact-form:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: -10px;
  right: -10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  border: 3px solid red;
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="contact-form-container">
  <form class="contact-form">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name">
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
    <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by adding an after element to the grid container and placing it under the content.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Answers that have actual code will help much better than a single sentence. As of now, this answer is more of a comment. Add code, show how it's done.

Comment: Please see [answer] and take the [tour].

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this design, you can declare a height on a grid or flex container that is shorter than the content and allow the content to overflow at the top and bottom by giving it center alignment.

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

div.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  height: 125px;
  gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  align-content: center;
  border: 3px solid firebrick;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div.container > div {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: silver;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work. I added display grid and a column schema while slightly modifying the top and bottom position of the before element. Also make sure the form doesnt have a color

For the record you were nearly there

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.contact-form-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}

.contact-form {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  gap: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.contact-form:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top:  30px;
  left: -10px;
  right: -10px;
  bottom:  30px;
  border: 3px solid red;
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="contact-form-container">
  <form class="contact-form">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name">
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
    <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```